# CakePHP4 - idea for database across multiple tables

Tags: database, join, model-view-controller, cakephp-4.x

I'm creating a body-wax comparison website for my own project with cakephp4 and I'm stuck with a problem right now and I dunno what to do.

```
Situation:
  There are multiple body-waxing companies, each company has many options for waxing like legs, arms, 
beard etc. And each company has different price range for each waxing part.

CompanyA->arms = $60
CompanyA->legs = $30
CompanyB->arms = $50
```

I already connected to the **Companies-table** and **Parts-table** like the image below. Additionally, I came up with the idea of Prices-table too but I'm not sure if it's doable or I need to come up with something else.

Hopefully, I want to edit the price in the companies edit/add pages.

Any help I would appreciate.

[image]

Comment: Why not just put the price in the `parts_tags` column?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Oh I thought the joinTable is for just connecting 2tables. I'm about to try